# How to display data from a Text file in a listView

Tags: java, android, listview

I've a plain text file which consist some lines, At the end of each line I insert a comma ( , ) . I also can read text files and set it on `ListView` but I don't know How can I make a new item in `ListView` by the lines that end with a comma . (I mean showing a single line in a single item.)

I've text file like this :

```
Test 1 ,
Test 2 ,
Test 3 ,
```

And this my `ListActity`:

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends ListActivity {
    public String[] ListItems = new String[]{};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
      try {
    Resources ResFiles = getResources();
        InputStream ReadDbFile = ResFiles.openRawResource(R.raw.test);
        byte[] Bytes = new byte[ReadDbFile.available()];
        ReadDbFile.read(Bytes);
        String DbLines = new String(Bytes);
        ListItems= new String[]{DbLines};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
           R.layout.main_list, R.id.ListText, ListItems);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
      } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

This `ListView` just showing me all lines in a single item , Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ListItems= new String[]{DbLines};` will give you an array of one item!

`DbLines.split(",")` might be better ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
String DbLines = new String(Bytes); // One string containing all the file
ListItems= new String[]{DbLines}; // an array containing the previous string
```

Why do you expect ListView to show multiple items? Try to split your file content in a string array, like this:

```
ListItems = DbLines.split(",");
```

In the end:

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends ListActivity {
    public String[] ListItems = new String[]{};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
      try {
    Resources ResFiles = getResources();
        InputStream ReadDbFile = ResFiles.openRawResource(R.raw.test);
        byte[] Bytes = new byte[ReadDbFile.available()];
        ReadDbFile.read(Bytes);
        String DbLines = new String(Bytes);
        ListItems = DbLines.split(","); // Split the content by ","
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
           R.layout.main_list, R.id.ListText, ListItems);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
      } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also split using:

```
DbLines.append("\r\n"); //Splits by NL

Test 1 
Test 2
Test 3
```

This was more appropriate for my code and may be for yours as well.  I believe there is a .lineseperator method but this works for me.